# Different settings for sys_log in database and log file

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i want to deactivate error logs in the database completely no error, no exception and no warning in the sys_log table in the database. I want to use a log file instead - all logging should happen only in this log file. (TYPO3 9 LTS)

Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems only possible with an own ExceptionHandler and overloading the method writeLogEntries() in TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\AbstractExceptionHandler:

```
protected function writeLogEntries(\Throwable $exception, $context) {

  // snip
  if ($this->logger) {
      $this->logger->critical($logTitle . ': ' . $logMessage, [
           'TYPO3_MODE' => TYPO3_MODE,
           'exception' => $exception
        ]);
  }
  // Write error message to sys_log table
  $this->writeLog($logTitle . ': ' . $logMessage);
}
```

There is no configuration possibility, every exception is written to log file and database.